# Regex pattern to grab url not working

Tags: java, regex

Let me get straight to my problem.

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "<span id=\"lblObject\"><a href=\"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=15135\" alt=\"View object\">Manual medicine guidelines for musculoskeletal injuries.</a></span>";

    //public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST ="<a href=\"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=1112\"></a>";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=(\\d+)\"");
        // in case you would like to ignore case sensitivity,
        // you could use this statement:
        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
        // check all occurance
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }


    }
```

There is some problem with the regex. The example string I have used is just a dummy string. Actually I will have a html file in which there are many url links which have the following pattern `http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=some_number`. I need to grab those links from that html file. Please guys can you help me find whats wrong with my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below program.

```
String htmlText = "<span id=\"lblObject\"><a href=\"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=15135\" alt=\"View object\">Manual medicine guidelines for musculoskeletal injuries.</a></span>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "href=\"(http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx\\?id=.*?)\"" );

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( htmlText );
    while ( matcher.find() )
    {
        String matchedText = matcher.group( 0 );
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(matchedText);
        String url = null;
        if (m.find()) {
            url = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }

// output : http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=15135
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the question mark `?` is a regex quantifier meaniong "one or none", but you are using it as a literal character: You must *escape* the question mark:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx\\?id=(\\d+)\"");
```

The key difference here is:

```
...content.aspx\\?id...
```

Notice the double backslash before the question mark, which is how in java you code a single backslash for the regex, so the pattern is `...content.aspx\?id...`

You regex doesn't have a question mark, but instead has zero-or-one `x` then `id`.

You should probably escape your dots too, but it's probably close enough as is.

Comment: `.` is also used by OP as a literal character here. Hopefully, it matches in the `EXAMPLE_TEST` a ... dot. :)

Comment: @Alex see the last sentence of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can quote your regex like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"\\Qhttp://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx?id=\\E(\\d+)\"");
```

> **\Q** tells the regex engine to quote the next part of the regex (ie ignore any metacharacter)
>    **\E** tells the regex engine that the quoted part is ended.

Comment: +1 For the often neglected **\Q** and **\E**. I find myself for too often escaping everything in sight when \Q .... \E would've been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was almost correct. The only error you made is not to escape the ? in `.aspx?id=`. If you only wanted to get the urls your pattern did also contain a bit to much information (the `<a href=\"`and the last `\"`). The correct patter to get only the URLs would be

```
"http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx\\?id=\\d+"
```

So using the following code snippet you should be able to extract all URLs

```
Pattern pattern = 
              Pattern.compile("http://www.guideline.gov/content.aspx\\?id=\\d+");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlText);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // do something
}
```